# Converting HTML to XML without losing any overlapping elements

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, html-agility-pack

I've got some HTML content that likely will have overlapping elements, like this example:

```
<p><em>Starts italic, then <strong>goes bold, then stops</em> being italic, then stops</strong> being bold.</p>
```

I need to convert this HTML to XHTML/XML. I wrote some code using the HTMLAgilityPack to do this:

```
var s = "<p><em>Starts italic, then <strong>goes bold, then stops</em> being italic, then stops</strong> being bold.</p>";

var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();

htmlDoc.OptionOutputOriginalCase = true;
htmlDoc.OptionWriteEmptyNodes = true;
htmlDoc.OptionOutputAsXml = true;
htmlDoc.OptionFixNestedTags = true;

htmlDoc.LoadHtml(s);

var output = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml;
```

However, the section of content that should be `strong` but not `em` ("`being italic, then stops`") is not inside a `strong` element, as shown in the value of the `output` variable from above:

```
<p><em>Starts italic, then <strong>goes bold, then stops</strong></em> being italic, then stops being bold.</p>
```

I have tried messing around with the various options on the HtmlDocument object to no avail.

This is the output that I am expecting:

```
<p><em>Starts italic, then <strong>goes bold, then stops</strong></em><strong> being italic, then stops</strong> being bold.</p>
```

.net 4.5, HTMLAgilityPack 1.4.0

Comment: After removing text from your html it is like this: `<p><em> <strong> </em> </strong> </p>` How do you expect a clean output?

Comment: Garbage in, garbage out? I know the input has unmatched tags, but I don't fully control the input in this case.

Comment: I'm pretty sure [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22661640/how-to-fix-ill-formed-html-with-html-agility-pack) from [the maker of HAP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/403671/simon-mourier) solves my problem.

Comment: Can I close this question as *duplicate* ?

Comment: Yes, please. I was just recording my close vote.