# Delete single tag from HTML document using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I have an HTML document that may contain unopened or unclosed tags. I'm using HtmlAgilityPack to find the errors, but once I do, I'd like to remove the broken tag from the document without affecting any of the other content. What's the best way to do this?

Here's my code so far:

```
HtmlDocument articleDoc = new HtmlDocument();
articleDoc.LoadHtml(article.ArticleBody);

if (articleDoc.ParseErrors != null && articleDoc.ParseErrors.Count() > 0) {
    foreach (HtmlParseError error in articleDoc.ParseErrors) {
        HtmlParseErrorCode eCode = error.Code;
        if (eCode == HtmlParseErrorCode.TagNotOpened || eCode == HtmlParseErrorCode.TagNotClosed) {
                           //Delete tag here

        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Instead of deleting them just fix them, here as an answer which can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22661640/how-to-fix-ill-formed-html-with-html-agility-pack

Comment: Thanks @mybirthname. I did see that other post, but I would really rather just be rid of the tags altogether.