# Correct html with missing <p> tag

Tags: c#, html, xml

Currently I am working on a solution to correct HTML. In our solution we have a rich text editor where we want to correct the HTML when the user forgets a `<p>` element, which happens a lot.

```
var input = new StringBuilder();
input.AppendLine("<h2>title1</h2>");
input.AppendLine("text");
input.AppendLine("<h2>title2</h2>");
input.AppendLine("<p>paragraph</p>");

var expected = new StringBuilder();
expected.AppendLine("<h2>title1</h2>");
expected.AppendLine("<p>text</p>");
expected.AppendLine("<h2>title2</h2>");
expected.AppendLine("<p>paragraph</p>");

Assert.AreEqual(expected.ToString(), input.DoSomething());
```

Is there something in the HTML agility pack? Of is there another solution?

Comment: Even if you don't use HTML AP, using a stringbuilder is just asking for trouble, there is a built in HTMLDocument class in .net that would be an improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that helps, but there is a similar topic:

[How to fix ill-formed HTML with HTML Agility Pack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22661640/how-to-fix-ill-formed-html-with-html-agility-pack)

Also, not your question, but we had good results with a Markdown Editor instead of an HTML Editor.