# Closing anchor tags with HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: html-agility-pack

I am using the HtmlAgilityPack to scrape crummy html and get links, raw text, etc. I'm running into a few pages that have inconsistently closed `<a>` tags, like this:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<a href=...>Here's a great link! <a href=...>Here's another one!</a> 
Here's some unrelated text.
</body></html>
```

HAP parses this, and helpfully closes the open `<a>` tag, but only at the very end of the document:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<a href="...">Here's a great link! <a href="...">Here's another one!</a>
Here's some unrelated text.
</a></body></html>
```

In practice this means that the `InnerText` of any unclosed link contains all text from the rest of the page, which gets exciting when parsing a page that may contain thousands of unclosed tags and megabytes of text.

So, how can I make HAP close those tags immediately, ideally putting the close just before the next open so that there is never any overlap for an `<a>`? I've played around with `OptionFixNestedTags` and `OptionAutoCloseOnEnd` with no luck, and I've found advice on how to allow overlap, but I'm drawing a blank on actually fixing it.

Comment: Fix nested tags works only on table related tags because it's possible w/o ambiguity (it could be added for ol/ul etc.). But for tags like A, it cannot be automatic. Only you knows where you want to put the missing </A>. More here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22661640/how-to-fix-ill-formed-html-with-html-agility-pack

Comment: It seems pretty straightforward (and unambiguous) to say it should be closed as soon as the nested open is encountered. As is, HAP does close those tags, it just waits until the end of the document to do it. I'd agree it needn't be a default behavior, but it would be a useful option.